# How to call a variable from a matrix... from a list?

Tags: r

Basically, it's in the title.
With more details though, I have four parameters set that need to be organised in matrices, that I organised in a list (Alphaset), each having 4 variables. But I need to call in specific variables into a loop where it will go through an equation and should give me a plot.

Me and my poor knowledge of R tried different combination that resulted in being inefficient, such as "Alphaset[2,1,1]" or "Alphaset[2(1,1)]" 
(this is an exemple where I want to display the variable that's first row first column of the second matrix).

```
#Parameters set on types (lambda 1, lambda 2, alphas)

Lambda1set<-c(5,5,3,3.2)
Lambda2set<-c(4,4,5,3)
Alphaset<-list(matrix(c(0.01, 0.007, 0.0045, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
            matrix(c(0.01, 0.003, 0.007, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
            matrix(c(0.01, 0.0055, 0.003, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
            matrix(c(0.005, 0.005, 0.0045, 0.004),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))

#Creating vectors
TimeVec<-seq(0,years,1)
N1<-matrix(0,4,years+1)
N2<-matrix(0,4,years+1)

#INITIALIZATION
N0 <- 40
N1[1] <-N0
N2[1] <-N0

for (t in 1:years){
  for(i in 1:4){
  N1[i,t+1]<-(Lambda1set[i]*N1[i,t])/(1+alphs[1,1]*N1[i,t]+alphs[1,2]*N2[i,t])
  N2[i,t+1]<-(lambda2set[i]*N2[i,t])/(1+alphs[2,1]*N1[i,t]+alphs[2,2]*N2[i,t])
  }
}

plot(TimeVec,N1,type="l",xlab='Time (years)',ylab='Population Density',col='blue', 
     lwd = 2,ylim = c(0,400))
```

Here you can see in the equations the "alphs[..,..]" are supposed to represent which variable from each i matrices I want to use.

But how do I call them in regard to my list of matrices ?

Comment: `years` is not defined.

Comment: A word on terminology: you don’t “call” variables, you call *functions*. You *use* or *read* variables.

Comment: was your question answered?

Comment: Yes thank you, I managed to get through it and without packages, which is very nice ! I used the list fonction and a secundary variable to help me call in the numbers I needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this?

```
years <- 10
Lambda1set<-c(5,5,3,3.2)
Lambda2set<-c(4,4,5,3)
Alphaset<-list(matrix(c(0.01, 0.007, 0.0045, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
               matrix(c(0.01, 0.003, 0.007, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
               matrix(c(0.01, 0.0055, 0.003, 0.01),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE),
               matrix(c(0.005, 0.005, 0.0045, 0.004),ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE))
dat <- lapply(1:length(Alphaset), function(i) {
  list(Lambda1=Lambda1set[i], Lambda2=Lambda2set[i], alphs=Alphaset[[i]])
})

#Creating vectors
TimeVec<-seq(0,years,1)
N1<-matrix(0,4,years+1)
N2<-matrix(0,4,years+1)

#INITIALIZATION
N0 <- 40

require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
lapply(seq_along(dat), function(i) {
  dati <- dat[[i]]
  N1 <- array(N0, dim=c(years+1))
  N2 <- array(N0, dim=c(years+1))
  for (t in 1:years) {
    N1[t+1]<-(dati$Lambda1*N1[t])/(1+dati$alphs[1,1]*N1[t]+dati$alphs[1,2]*N2[t])
    N2[t+1]<-(dati$Lambda2*N2[t])/(1+dati$alphs[2,1]*N1[t]+dati$alphs[2,2]*N2[t])
  }
  return(data.frame(i=i, Time=TimeVec, N1=N1, N2=N2))
}) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  mutate(i=factor(i)) %>%
  gather("Variable", "Value", -Time, -i) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=Time, y=Value, color=Variable)) +
    geom_line() +
    ylab("Population Density") +
    theme_bw() +
    facet_grid(i~.)
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Yes, with much more details and knowledge of r, I believe it would look like this ! Thank you so much, I will use this to make my code work.

However I am trying not to use packages here, to simplify the process but I'll take this nevertheless.

Comment: Why are you not trying to use packages? `dplyr`, `tidyverse`, and `ggplot` are considered to be the gold standard of `R` programming, and their usefulness for this exact problem are basically the bread and butter of what makes R great :) they are generally accepted to be standard amongst the R community, and are typically the preferred approach to doing things if the programmer has familiarity with them, due to the cleanness of the resulting code

Comment: Yes, I am studying them and how to use them properly, I recognize their importance fully ! Thank you again (:

Answer (score 0):

Just define the `alphs` variable as follow:

```
alphs <- Alphaset[[i]]
```

just after the line 21: `for(i in 1:4){`

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, however, it didn't seem to work because the time vector was a sequence, so I turned it into a matrix similar to N1 and N2 and it gave me off only one graph, which was nonsensical. I'm obviously trying to have four graphs with each variables set as outcomes, I am sorry I should have pointed this out, maybe ?